# Get topmost CPU usage PID and output it to a file

Tags: linux, process, cpu-usage

I want to count the CPU usage approximately but I don't want to use accton or any other software. Just only script.
Can I use top to get the topmost CPU usage or memory usage's process name?
When I use top -b I get a lot of unuseful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cpu usage:

```
ps -eo comm,%cpu --no-headers | sort -k2 -nr | head -1
```

For memory:

```
 ps -eo comm,%mem --no-headers | sort -k2 -nr | head -1
```